Hola tengo problemas en la aplicación JFLAP
no me muestra las letras en el output en la table text size en la aplicacion JFLAP
este es el ejercicio que estoy realizando :
Una cadena compuesta con 0 y 1, debe convertir cada 0 en 1 y cada 1 en 0.


Hola Andrés, la verdad no entendí tu pregunta y necesito más detalles de lo que quieres hacer para poder ayudarte.

Por último, no has puesto ejemplos en los lenguajes que mencionas en las etiquetas, así que deberías poner una etiqueta que se adecué a tu pregunta.
